# Can a superposition of a travelling wave and a standing wave give a standing wave?

Tags: waves, superposition

I have two similar questions:

1) I have heard, that a travelling wave can be understood as a superposition of standing waves. Can you exaplain this (some images would be wonderful)?

2) Can a superposition of a travelling wave and a standing wave give a standing wave (I suppose it cannot, but I don't knwo how to prove it)?

Comment: In (1), did you mean to say that a standing wave can be understood as a superposition of travelling waves? If not, the statement is incorrect: two standing waves will produce another standing wave.

Comment: Consider either the energy or moment transport of the wave and the correct answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Straight from [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standing_wave_2.gif)

   [image]
2. A standing wave, by definition, has the property all points along the wave are moving in phase with each other.  A traveling wave does not, in general, have this property.  If we superpose the two, then two points A & B will move in a superposition of an in-phase oscillation and an out-of-phase oscillation;  and it is impossible to add together an in-phase oscillation with an out-of-phase oscillation to get an in-phase oscillation.  Thus, a standing wave superposed with a traveling wave cannot yield a standing wave.